# Passing a user input string in a different function in C++

Tags: c++, function

I am very new to C++ and I am having a difficult time passing by reference/value?

I am attempting to pass the user input string from the get_sentence function into the replace_message function and replace the characters with underscores, but I it will not do that?

I am sorry if this is not specific enough, but I could really use some help.

```
int main() {
    string hidden, public_string;
    get_sentence();
    replace_message(hidden);
    return 0;
}

string get_sentence() {
    string hidden;
    cout << "Enter a message: ";
    getline (cin, hidden);
    return hidden;
}         

string replace_message(string &hidden) {
    string public_string;
     hidden = public_string;
    for(int i=0; i< public_string.length(); i++) {
      if(public_string[i] != ' ')
         public_string[i] = '_';
    }
    cout << "The message is" << public_string << endl;
    return public_string;
}
```

Comment: Is C++ your first OO language? If yes, I'd recommend learning something easier to grasp the basics of procedural programming and OO paradigm. I'd go for C#, but Java would work as well. With C++, you can run in all sorts of seemingly weird problems.

Comment: At my school they start us with C++ so everything will seem easier afterward.

Comment: Well... it certainly will, there is no arguing with that. Good luck then!

Answer (score 5):

Modify your `main()` method to use the result which is returned from the `get_sentence()` function:

```
int main() {
    string hidden, public_string;

    hidden = get_sentence();      // store user message here
    replace_message(hidden);      // and pass it here

    return 0;
}
```

You should also modify your `replace_message()` function to use the input you pass to it:

```
string replace_message(string &hidden) {
    string public_string = hidden;

    for (int i=0; i< public_string.length(); i++)
    {
        if (public_string[i] != ' ')
            public_string[i] = '_';
    }

    cout << "The message is" << public_string << endl;

    return public_string;
}
```

Comment: What is the use of returning `public_string` by `replace_message` if the returned string isn't stored in main? It would seem to make more sense if the function was `void`.

Comment: @RHertel Good point.  He could consider making the function `void`, or if he actually intends to use the returned string later in his software project, he could leave it as is.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main(){
string hidden;

hidden = get_sentence();

replace_message(hidden);

return 0;
}
```

You function is returning a value but you have to store that in a variable. Your replace_message function is also buggy because you are assigning and unintialized string public_string to your original message in the variable hidden. Do it as follows

```
void replace_message(string &hidden){

for(int i=0; i< hidden.length(); i++)
{
  if(hidden[i] != ' ')
     hidden[i] = '_';
}

cout << "The message is" << hidden << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also avoid the loop and use `std::regex_replace` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string get_sentence() {
    string hidden;
    cout << "Enter a message: ";
    getline (cin, hidden);
    return hidden;
}         

string replace_message(string &hidden) {
  regex non_blank("\\S"); // selects everything but whitespace characters
  string public_string = regex_replace(hidden, non_blank, "_");
  return public_string;
}

int main() {
    string hidden, public_string;
    hidden = get_sentence();
    public_string = replace_message(hidden);
    cout << "The message is: " << public_string << endl;
    return 0;
}
```